# How to handle changed API results with Paging 3 and LazyColumn (LazyPagingItems) in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, paging3

I have API endpoint that returns a list of objects. I am using Paging 3 with pagingSource, flow in ViewModel, and collectAsLazyPagingItems. This list is passed to LazyColumn to show items on screen.

In LazyColumn items look like this

```
                        items(
                            count = list.itemCount,
                            key = list.itemKey { it.uuid },
                            contentType = list.itemContentType { it }
                        ) { // composable here }
```

For example, I fetch 50 items on the first page (and the last item in the list has uuid: "xxx"). Scroll to the bottom and the new 50 items contain this item xxx, because the order was changed on the server while I was scrolling. And now I get the next error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Key was already used
```

I don't want to remove unique keys from LazyColumn, because it improves performance. Are there any other ways to handle this case? What can I do to prevent this error while still using Paging 3?

Comment: If your data changes, your `PagingSource` needs to `invalidate` itself so that its data is reloaded, thus ensuring that the item no longer exists in its old location. Where have you hooked up your server side changes up to Paging?

Comment: @piotrpawlowski in PagingSource, in load function I filter response for duplicates before return LoadResult